# Disable the browser secure/insecure content prompt programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, http, browser, https, activex

We have a sharepoint 2007 site which has been set up on HTTPS. this site has many pages which have external content referenced from other sites which are not setup on https. The content is some rss feeds, images and the like. Now whenever the user opens the sharepoint site it gets a prompt from the browser saying if the user wants to see the insecure content or not. We have a very huge user base and we cannot go to every machine and set the browser settings to show the insecure content or add the site to the trusted zone. is there some way in which we can programmatically enable the browser to show the insecure content? Possibly using either an active x or something ? Please let me know what could be a possible solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your systems are on a domain and running IE, you can probably do this with Group Policy Objects.

GPO registry keys from some IE settings: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775996(WS.10).aspx

Comment: we considered this solution but our site is visible on internet and we cant implement group policy on all the user's machines

Comment: Without the ability to come in from the back (like with GPO) your options are limitied.  Frankly, it's a good thing this isn't easy, because it would be rampantly abused by unsavory folk.

Comment: I agree with Justin, it wouldn't be desirable to allow incoming web content to somehow bypass the safety measures implemented in the browser. This is a change that has to be affected at the browser from the user context.

Answer (score 1):

You could use your own web server as a proxy, [one possible example here](http://www.iisproxy.net/). I haven't tested it, just took the first hit it in google. I'm not very used to proxying on IIS but have already used `mod_proxy` on apache.

You would then route all the traffic to external sites through your https: proxy and avoid the warning on the clients.

In my eyes, this has two majour advantages:

1. You do not have to trade security for comfort
2. You have a central point of administration.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the XSL Code. Replace "GetSafe.html" with this.

```
 <xsl:template name="GetSafeHtml">
            <xsl:param name="Html"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$rss_IsDesignMode = 'True'">
                    <xsl:call-template name="strip-tags">
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$Html"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:call-template name="strip-tags">
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="rssaggwrt:MakeSafe($Html)"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="strip-tags">
            <xsl:param name="text"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($text, '&lt;')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, '&lt;')"/>
                    <xsl:call-template name="strip-tags">
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, '&gt;')"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>
```